# making floated div fill vertical space when that space is dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Div A                                  |
|                                        |
|  +----------+   +-------------------+  |
|  | Div B    |   | Div C             |  |
|  |          |   |                   |  |
|  +----------+   |                   |  |
|                 |                   |  |
?                 ?                   ?  ?
|                 +-------------------+  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Div A contains both B and C.

Div B will only ever hold one line of content.

Div C contains a list of variable item count, so the height is highly variable.

Divs B and C have set widths.

Div C's height drives the height of Div A.

**How can I make Div B expand vertically to match the unknown height of Div C?**

*For a variety of reasons not worth getting into, tables would not work in this situation.*

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this awhile ago and I found this:

http://abcoder.com/css/css-equal-height-columns/

There are solutions for using jQuery or with pure CSS. It worked for me and I hope it's what you're looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Link is dead. Hence why linking in answers is frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do such a thing, it's called "[Faux Column](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)s".

There is a way descried on [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/breaking-out-of-the-box/), there are [a few more ways](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61), and there's a way using CSS3 gradient described by [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-mimic-equal-columns-with-css3-gradients/)

BTW, all of these methods use CSS only, without JavaScript

Comment: The link points to a google search of Faux Columns, I think something more specific to code would be better instead of bird feeders etc.

Comment: You're right, @Peege151. On the other hand, this whole answer is not so relevant nowadays that there is`flex`, `flex` solves the problem easily,

Answer (score 0):

If you set Div A's height, you can then set the height of Div B to 100%

```
#divA{height:700px;}
#divB{height:100%;}
```

or if you're trying to make a 2 column webpage layout you can work off of the body

```
body{height:100%;}
#divA{height:auto;}
#divB{min-height:100%;}
```

and here is a Javascript solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var h = document.getElementById("divA").offsetHeight;
     document.getElementById("divB").style.height = h + "px";
</script>
```